# adding 64-bit integers in 16-bit pieces with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have two objects, `this` and `that`, each with properties `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` that represent the highest, second-highest, second-lowest and lowest 16-bit pieces that represent a 64-bit unsigned integer in each.

- Would this be a correct way to add them, that works in all cases?
- Is it the most efficient, or can it be improved?

---

```
var a = this.a + that.a,
    b = this.b + that.b,
    c = this.c + that.c,
    d = this.d + that.d;
if (d > 0xffff)
    c += d >> 16,
    d %= d % 0xffff;
if (c > 0xffff)
    b += c >> 16,
    c %= 0xffff;
if (b > 0xffff)
    a += b >> 16,
    b %= 0xffff;
if (a > 0xffff)
    a %= 0xffff;
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
this.c = c;
this.d = d;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are bugs in that code.

`d %= d % 0xffff;` should be `d %= 0x10000;`.

`c %= 0xffff;` should be `c %= 0x10000;`, and then the same for `b` and `a`.

Instead of first adding and then handle carry, you can start with the lowest component and use the carry from that for the next component:

```
var d = this.d + that.d;
var c = this.c + that.c + (d >> 16);
d &= 0xffff;
var b = this.b + that.b + (c >> 16);
c &= 0xffff;
var a = this.a + that.a + (b >> 16);
b &= 0xffff;
```

This will leave a possible overflow in `a`, if you want to ignore that you can just do `a &= 0xffff;`, otherwise you can report an error `if (a > 0xffff)`.